# special characters to 'normal' equivalents

Tags: php

How to convert this characters.
***eg. converting 'VýchodnýSlovensko' to 'v-yacute-chodn-eacute-slovensko'***

Comment: Is that literally what you want? Or `Vy'chodny'Slovensko`? (You seem to have changed a `y` to an `e`…)

Comment: check this out.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php And if you want to insert into database then you can use ckEditor for this use

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

```
htmlentities('VýchodnýSlovensko', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); // returns V&yacute;chodn&yacute;Slovensko
```

Or maybe you want this:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8');
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', 'VýchodnýSlovensko'); // outputs VychodnySlovensko
```

Comment: so you want "V-yacute-chodn-yacute-Slovensko", not "V&yacute;chodn&yacute;Slovensko" or "VychodnySlovensko"?

Comment: your output is 'VchodnSlovensko' not this 'VychodnySlovensko'.

Comment: give me perfect output, see: 'VychodnySlovensko'

Comment: what encoding are you using for your input string? setlocale() and iconv() gives your desired output with utf-8 encoded input on multiple machines.